# How to make a gif clickable to a new page?

Tags: hyperlink, gif, clickable

I would like to make a gif clickable to a new page. I'm not sure what code to include and have tried many options that did not work out. The following is part of the code:

`<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-image: url('xx.gif'); background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%;" id="xx" data-image-url="xx.gif">`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. HTML link use the `<a>` tag with the intended URL in the href property. Wrap your GIF in an `<a>` tag to make it clickable.